# Есть ли в clojure аналог describe из CL?

Tags: lisp, clojure

Есть ли в clojure аналог describe из CL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу на собственный вопрос чтобы не висел без ответа.

doc - выводит документацию по команде

source - выводит исходный код, если это возможно